# "Very well so" correctness and formality?

Tags: grammar, formality

Person 1: "I hope I answered all your questions."

Person 2: "Yes, you did, very well so."

Is the "very well so" grammatically correct? What about formality?

Comment: The 'so' doesn't belong there at all. What's your justification for it?

Comment: It seems like an odd amalgam of "very well" and "quite so". I can't find any backing for this usage, all hits are phrases like "very well so far" etc.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski Astralbee is right, I was confusing it with "very much so" which is used commonly. Although I'm not sure why one works and the other doesn't, grammatically speaking.

Comment: "Yes, you did so, very well" would be correct.

Comment: Or "...very well too" - would also work. The word "so" (in Britain) seems to me to be creeping into the speech of a lot of people as a kind of filler. (There is a more technical word than "filler" that linguistics people use, but I can't think what it is.) For example, I find that if I ask directions or an explanation of younger people, they will often start with the word "So..." It is quite foreign to anyone who has been around as many decades as I have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Very well so" is **not** idiomatic. You are possibly confusing it with the idiomatic "*very **much** so*", which is an emphatic way of answering a question to which the answer could simply be "yes".

You could use "very much so" in response to the question in your example which might perhaps mean that the questions were answered *thoroughly*. Or, you could instead say "*yes, you answered them very well*" which might better describe the *manner* in which they were answered.

"Very much so" can sound semi-formal but it would not be out of place in informal speech - it is a common phrase used by native speakers in all kinds of settings.

Comment: You are right. I was confusing it with "very much so". The intention was to describe that the answers were thorough AND delivered well. But why isn't "very well so" idiomatic when "very much so" is? Is it an exception made for "much" in that context but not for other adverbs?

Comment: @WalksB Honestly, I couldn't say with authority, but it may have to do with whether something is *quantifiable* or not. "Very much" can describe a quantity, amount, or degree of something. "Very well" describes the *quality* or *completeness* of something, but not a quantity. We also say "*all the **more** so", 'more' also being an adverb of quantity, or amount.

Answer (score 0):

**"Very well so"** is grammatically wrong. You can say: **"Yes,you did so,very well"** or **"Yes,you did it,very well"** or **"Yes,you did that,very well"** or **"Yes,you did it,very much so"** or **"Yes,you did that,very much so"** or **"Yes,you did so,very much so".**

The phrase **"very much so"** is a formal idiom.**"Very much so"** means **"very,very much."**

I found in EnglishCLUB [1](https://www.englishclub.com/ref/esl/Conversational_Phrases/V/very_much_so_4416.php) the following:

> **Very much so:** This is a formal way of saying "Yes, very much".
>
> **Examples:**
>
> - -Do you like your new job, Alex? 
>   -Yes, very much so.
> - -Did you enjoy your holiday in Monaco, Vivien?  
>   -Very much so. It was delightful.

Comment: I think **very well** in your answer is different from the OP usage. In the OP it doesn't mean *yes*, it means *completely* or *excellently*. (Perhaps this is made harder to see because of the comma before the phrase.)

Comment: That *you did so very well* works doesn't mean \**you did, very well so* does - I agree with Astralbee's answer on this. The only way this arrangement of words works for me is interpreting it as *yes, you did, very well, so* - *yes, you did, alright, anyway*, conveying a very different tone than OP intended.

Comment: @MariosAthanasiou I believe mentions don't work (don't show up in the inbox) unless a person posted or commented under that specific post. You can make a comment on Astralbee's answer if you disagree with it and ask for clarifications there.