# Do the sentences "Yes, you did, very well so" and "Yes, you did so very well" have the same meaning?

Tags: sentence-meaning, idioms

Consider the following sentences:

> 1. Yes, you did, very well so.
> 2. Yes, you did so very well.

Do those sentences have exactly the same meaning? If they don't have the same meaning, can someone explain to me their meanings?

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/341611/very-well-so-correctness-and-formality for context.

Comment: Neither of them means anything in current English.

Comment: 'very well so' means nothing. 'so very well' sounds like you're complimenting a small child for tying their shoelaces without assistance.

Comment: To help those learning English, note that the OP question has some mistakes. "Do that sentences..." should be "Do those sentences..." (to match the plural). And "In case they don't..." is not wrong, but the more likely expression is "If they don't..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sentence 1 is simply wrong. The idion is "very much so", and is explained in the reference given in the comments.

Sentence 2 is a valid sentence, but its meaning is slightly ambiguous. The word "**so**" is used to qualify other words and has a wide range of meanings. As punctuated, it probably means "*You did X not just very well, but so very well.*" It's an intensifier. We would get the same result if we said "You did very, very well".

However, if we read **so** as qualifying the verb, "you did", the sentence would mean *You did so (the thing implied by the previous conversation), and you did it very well.* If I wanted to retain these words and make this meaning clear, I would add a comma after the word **so**.

Comment: Hi! I edited again my question in the way you told me! I have accepted your answer! I also upvoted it!Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: You got confused and in the first sentence you wrote 'idion' instead of 'idiom'. Is English your mother language?

Comment: Ha! Just a typo. Good spotting.

Comment: Hi! We say "You did (it) very, very well". We omitted the word "it". Is the sentence correct without the word "it"?

Comment: Either is fine. I can say to my son "You did your homework well", or "You did well" (with us both understanding that I'm referring to the homework.) They mean the same.

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much!